# Object doesn't show when trying to use boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

I made a model by joining multiple objects. now I want to remove the intersected parts. I've read that you can use the boolean modifier for this but now it doesn' work.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

[image]

Comment: Why not trying the remesh, booleans can be temperamental

Comment: I am not shure if it was the best solution but I found a way with the help of a person on reddit. I seperated the parts again. And used the union modifier. That solved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, breaking Ng it to small parts and doing each Boolean individually usually works. Good luck